# insert graphics in cool tool tips

Tags: graphics

Is there a way to include graphics in cooltooltips argument?
like

```
\cooltooltip[0.5 0.25 1]{Example}%
    {\includegraphics{graphic}}%
    {http://www.panoramio.com/user/4366708}{Visit my site}{My Name\strut}
```

thanks in Advance.

Comment: It would be helpful if you composed a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that sets up the problem.

While solving problems can be fun, setting them up is not. Then, those trying to help can simply cut and paste your MWE and get started on solving the problem.

Answer (score 4):

No, the `\cooltooltip` macro from the package of the same name cannot, but the `\coolToolTip` macro defined below can. It takes the same arguments as the original:

```
\coolToolTip[<popup colour>][<link colour>]
  {<subject>}
  {<message>}
  {<URL>}
  {<tooltip>}
  {<link text>}
```

The URL is opened in a separate browser window after clicking the message box.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{scrbook}

\usepackage{graphicx}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% usage:
%
% \coolToolTip[<popup colour>][<link colour>]{<subject>}{<message>}{<URL>}{<tooltip>}{<link text>}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{media9}
\usepackage{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\let\tpPdfLink\mix_pdflink:nn
\let\tpPdfAnnot\mix_pdfannot:nnnn\def\tpPdfLastAnn{\g_mix_pdflastann_tl}
\let\tpPdfXform\mix_pdfxform:n\def\tpPdfLastXform{\g_mix_pdflastxform_tl}
\let\tpPdfObj\mix_pdfobj:nnn\def\tpPdfLastObj{\g_mix_pdflastobj_tl}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\coolToolTip}{O{0 1 0}O{0 1 0}mmmmm}{{%
  \leavevmode%
  \tpPdfObj{}{dict}{/Type/OCG/Name (tipOCG.\thetcnt)%
    /Usage<</Print<</PrintState/OFF>>/Export<</ExportState/OFF>>>>%
  }%
  \xdef\@anim@ocgs{\@anim@ocgs\space\tpPdfLastObj}%
  \xdef\@anim@offocgs{\@anim@offocgs\space\tpPdfLastObj}%
  \edef\tpTipOcg{\tpPdfLastObj}%
  \tpPdfObj{}{dict}{/Type/OCG/Name (msgOCG.\thetcnt)%
    /Usage<</Print<</PrintState/OFF>>/Export<</ExportState/OFF>>>>%
  }%
  \xdef\@anim@ocgs{\@anim@ocgs\space\tpPdfLastObj}%
  \xdef\@anim@offocgs{\@anim@offocgs\space\tpPdfLastObj}%
  \edef\tpMsgOcg{\tpPdfLastObj}%
  \tpPdfLink{%
    /Subtype/Screen%
    /AA<<%
      /E<</S/SetOCGState/State [/ON \tpTipOcg]>>%
      /X<</S/SetOCGState/State [/OFF \tpTipOcg]>>%
      /D<</S/SetOCGState/State [/Toggle \tpMsgOcg]>>%
    >>%
  }{{\color[rgb]{#2}#7}}%
  \sbox\tiptext{\fcolorbox[rgb]{0 0 0}{1 1 0.75}{#6}}%
  \edef\twd{\the\wd\tiptext}%
  \edef\tht{\the\ht\tiptext}%
  \edef\tdp{\the\dp\tiptext}%
  \measureremainder{\whatsleft}\tipshift=0pt%
  \ifdim\whatsleft<\twd\setlength\tipshift{\whatsleft-\twd}\fi%
  \tpPdfXform{\tiptext}%
  \raisebox{\heightof{#7}}[0pt][0pt]{\makebox[0pt][l]{\hspace{\tipshift}%
    \tpPdfAnnot{\twd}{\tht}{\tdp}{%
      /Subtype/Widget/FT/Btn/Ff 65537/T (tip:\thetcnt)%
      /AP<</N \tpPdfLastXform>>%
      /MK<</TP 1/I \tpPdfLastXform/IF<</S/A/FB true/A [0.0 0.0]>>>>%
      /OC \tpTipOcg
    }%
    \xdef\@anim@fields{\@anim@fields\space\tpPdfLastAnn}%
  }}%
  \sbox\tiptext{\fcolorbox[rgb]{0 0 0}{#1}{\vbox{\hbox{#3}\hbox{#4}}}}%
  \edef\twd{\the\wd\tiptext}%
  \edef\tht{\the\ht\tiptext}%
  \edef\tdp{\the\dp\tiptext}%
  \measureremainder{\whatsleft}\tipshift=0pt%
  \ifdim\whatsleft<\twd\setlength\tipshift{\whatsleft-\twd}\fi%
  \tpPdfXform{\tiptext}%
  \raisebox{\heightof{#7}}[0pt][0pt]{\makebox[0pt][l]{\hspace{\tipshift}%
    \tpPdfAnnot{\twd}{\tht}{\tdp}{%
      /Subtype/Widget/FT/Btn/Ff 65536/T (msg:\thetcnt)%
      /AP<</N \tpPdfLastXform>>%
      /MK<</TP 1/I \tpPdfLastXform/IF<</S/A/FB true/A [0.0 0.0]>>>>%
      /A<</S/URI/URI (#5)>>%
      /OC \tpMsgOcg
    }%
    \xdef\@anim@fields{\@anim@fields\space\tpPdfLastAnn}%
  }}%
  \stepcounter{tcnt}%
}}
\makeatother
\newsavebox\tiptext\newcounter{tcnt}
\newlength{\whatsleft}\newlength{\tipshift}
\newcommand{\measureremainder}[1]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
    \path let \p0 = (0,0), \p1 = (current page.east) in
      [/utils/exec={\pgfmathsetlength#1{\x1-\x0}\global#1=#1}];
  \end{tikzpicture}%
} 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

Join the \coolToolTip[0.8 0.4 1][0 0 1]{\small Visit:}{\includegraphics[width=2cm]{tuglogo}}{http://www.tug.org}{\small Visit the TUG}{TUG}!

\end{document}
```